# Cálculo da latência do evento load com objeto window.performance

Tags: javascript

O tempo entre o atributo `window.performance.timing.connecStart` e `window.performance.timing.loadEventStart` seria o tempo que levou para que o evento `window.onload` fosse disparado? Digo, desde a conexão até o *callback* do `onload` ser executado?

Tenho a seguinte função (faz parte de uma pequena lib minha):

```
pageLoad: function() {
    var start, end, total;      
    start = window.performance.timing.connectStart;
    end = window.performance.timing.loadEventStart; 
    total = end - start;
    console.log(total + "ms para disparar o evento window.onload");
    return total;
}
```

Essa função está pegando com precisão o intervalo da conexão até o evento `window.onload` ser disparado? Se não, de que forma eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Pela documentação da MDN parece ser isso mesmo. Há algumas ressalvas sobre o valor de `connectStart` quando a conexão está pré-estabelecida, mas acho que não interfere na sua lógica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com as recomendações da W3C acerca do objeto [`PerformanceTiming`](https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#performancetiming) representado por `window.performance.timing`:

> `connectStart` attribute
>
> *This attribute must return the time immediately before the user agent start establishing the connection to the server to retrieve the document. If a persistent connection [RFC 2616] is used or the current document is retrieved from relevant application caches or local resources, this attribute must return value of domainLookupEnd.*

Este atributo deve retornar o tempo imediatamente antes do *user agent* iniciar a tentativa de estabelecer a conexão com o servidor para receber o documento em questão. Se existir uma conexão persistente [RFC 2616] ou o documento é recebido do sistema de cachê ou recursos locais, este atributo deve retornar o valor de `domainLookupEnd`.

> `loadEventStart` attribute
>
> *This attribute must return the time immediately before the load event of the current document is fired. It must return zero when the load event is not fired yet.*

Este atributo deve retornar o tempo imediatamente antes do evento `load` do documento atual ser disparado. Deve retornar zero enquanto o evento não tiver sido disparado.

Ou seja, considerando que o primeiro define o tempo que o *user agent* estabelece a conexão com o servidor e o segundo o tempo em que o evento `load` será disparado, acredito que faça sentido definir como latência (relativa) deste mesmo evento a diferença entre esses dois valores.